# I would like to use Basic Authentication in IFRAME tag in xwiki

Tags: iframe, basic-authentication, xwiki

for example:

< frame class=“myclass” src=“http://superadmin:admin@myserver/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome?basicauth=1”>

but doesn’t load content of iframe, is it possible ? or not? if this not possible how can i make auto login in xwikiiframe?

i’m already use ldap authentication and this is jsf project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it works, but you're probably hitting an issue related to not respecting the Same Origin Policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Basically, the `myserver` part of the iframe's `src` attribute is different from the current host you are loading the HTML from. Either that or it uses a different protocol (i.e. `https` vs `http`).

Check the browser console for more information where you should find the exact reason why the browser refused to load your iframe.

*Edit*: Also note that [basic auth URLs have been deprecated for a while now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Access_using_credentials_in_the_URL) and you should try to avoid them completely, as browsers have started deprecating or dropping this feature completely (most notably, Chrome is among the most aggressive). See https://medium.com/@lmakarov/say-goodbye-to-urls-with-embedded-credentials-b051f6c7b6a3 for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I got this message.
Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

Comment: I think, i understand what is the problem, but i dont know, how can i fix it.

Comment: Yes, Chrome is especially bad if you want basic auth URLs. Please see my edit above. I recommend that you try a different approach, either by allowing view rights for guests on the specific pages that have a public nature or by asking users to visit the specific pages with their own credentials.